# docker-compose up failed with the following error failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Detailed error below:-**
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/ masked url : unexpected EOF

Environment :-
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
O

OS :-
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042

Answer (score 8):

There was a experimental feature **Use Docker Compose V2** was enabled.
When disabled this option , docker-compose up started working.