# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code

Tags: node.js, docker, unit-testing, docker-compose, dockerfile

The following are the files that are associated with the query and the commands I ran which led to these errors:

Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

FROM base as test
RUN npm ci --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "test" ]

FROM base as prod
RUN npm ci --production --silent
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  customer_api:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/server
    command: npm start
```

Command run:

> docker build -t customer --target prod .

Error stack trace [with buildkit]

```
[+] Building 7.6s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                                                 5.3s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:9ba7531bd80fb0a858632727cf7a112fbfd19b17e94c4e84ced81e24ef1a0dbc                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                       0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest                                                                                       2.0s
 => [auth] library/base:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

Error stack trace [without buildkit]

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  785.9kB
Step 1/13 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> 5dcd1f6157bd
Step 2/13 : WORKDIR /server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 838d1ca2775c
Step 3/13 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
 ---> 20c41a2cf967
Step 4/13 : FROM base as test
pull access denied for base, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Command run:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml run customer_api npm run test
```

Error stack trace

```
WARNING: Found orphan containers (node_customer-api_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Creating node_customer_api_run ... done

> node@1.0.0 test
> mocha ./**/*.test.js --exit
 
Customer CRUD
    Create customer
      1) should create customer asynchronously

1) Customer CRUD
       Create customer
         should create customer asynchronously:
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16)
```

None of the following solutions worked in my case hence the question:

1. docker-compose up error: "failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0" - Stack Overflow
   [docker-compose up error: "failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70506097/docker-compose-up-error-failed-to-solve-rpc-error-code-unknown-desc-fail)
2. go - ERROR: dockerfile parse error invalid field ' ' - Stack Overflow
   [ERROR: dockerfile parse error invalid field ' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515162/error-dockerfile-parse-error-invalid-field)
3. docker-compose up failed with the following error failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: - Stack Overflow
   [docker-compose up failed with the following error failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68132183/docker-compose-up-failed-with-the-following-error-failed-to-solve-rpc-error-co)
4. node.js - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 - Stack Overflow
   [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71821415/error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-15432)
5. docker - An error, "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0" - Stack Overflow
   [An error, "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221861/an-error-failed-to-solve-with-frontend-dockerfile-v0)
6. dockerfile - denied: requested access to the resource is denied: docker - Stack Overflow
   [denied: requested access to the resource is denied: docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984399/denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied-docker)
7. node.js - Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 in docker-compose while connecting redis - Stack Overflow
   [Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 in docker-compose while connecting redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71717395/getting-error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-16379-in-docker-compose-while-conne)
8. node.js - Docker Compose getting error ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 with MySQL and NodeJS - Stack Overflow
   [Docker Compose getting error ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 with MySQL and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512831/docker-compose-getting-error-econnrefused-127-0-0-13306-with-mysql-and-nodejs)

Comment: what docker repository do you think `base` should be?  Looks to me like it was supposed to be a build stage, and `FROM node:lts-alpine` should be `FROM node:lts-alpine AS base`

Comment: Thanks! that sorted the issue in the Dockerfile